# Javascript (jQuery) failing to re-append using clicker counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use javascript to append some input forms when a button is clicked, and then on the second click of the same button, I wish to remove those fields using the `.remove()` method. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loginCount = 0;

  document.getElementById("login-button").onclick=function(){
    loginCount++;

    if (loginCount == 1)
    {
      $("#containerz").append('<div class="form-group"><input type="email" name="email" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Existing email address" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="email-field"></div><div class="form-group"><input type="password" name="password" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Password123" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="password-field"></div>');
    }else if  (loginCount == 2)
    {
      $("#containerz").remove();
      loginCount = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='login-button'>Login</button>
<div id='containerz'>

</div>
```

The result of testing this was that clicking the button the first time appends properly. Clicking it the second time removes properly. Every click afterward fails to re-append. Debugging showed me that `loginCount` was indeed set back to 0 after clicking the 2nd time and that it is incremented to 1 on the third click just before it ought to re-append.

Am I understanding the append and remove methods incorrectly? Can I no longer append after having removed?

Comment: This is because you are removing `#containerz` in your second click, so when third click, jQuery will not find it to append contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the jQuery method **[`empty()`](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)** that will remove all child nodes of `containerz` from the DOM instead of **[`remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)** that will remove the `containerz` it self from the DOM definitely so in the next click your function can't find the container to append the content to :

```
$("#containerz").empty();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var loginCount = 0;

  document.getElementById("login-button").onclick=function(){
    loginCount++;

    if (loginCount == 1)
    {
      $("#containerz").append('<div class="form-group"><input type="email" name="email" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Existing email address" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="email-field"></div><div class="form-group"><input type="password" name="password" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Password123" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="password-field"></div>');
    }else if  (loginCount == 2)
    {
      $("#containerz").empty();
      loginCount = 0;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='login-button'>Login</button>
<div id='containerz'>

</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I had the wrong conception of what remove did.

Answer (score 0):

You are removing whole container, so there is nothing to append to after second click.

Replace

```
$("#containerz").remove();
```

with:

```
$("#containerz").find('.form-group').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the jQuery [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login-button").on('click', function() {
    $("#containerz").toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
#containerz {
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='login-button'>Login</button>
<div id='containerz'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" name="email" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Existing email address" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="email-field">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" style="color:#bcbcbc;" value="Password123" onfocus="inputFocus(this)" onblur="inputBlur(this)" class="form-control field-bar" id="password-field">
  </div>
</div>
```